# Validation and verification: exception handling within a function in python

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to create an add() function that add integers. I am having trouble with the exception handling as I would optimally like to have one isinstance call that can do the verification and validation that I need. Right now have raised three exceptions errors for three scenarios:

1. if there are no arguments.
2. If the inputs are list, set, tuples.
3. if the arguments are not integers: strings and floats.

This is my current implementation:

```
def add(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        raise TypeError("add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'")

    integer_total = 0

    for numbers in args:
        if isinstance(numbers, (list, set, tuple)):
            raise TypeError("add() does not accept lists, sets, or tuples as arguments")
        elif not isinstance(numbers, int):
            raise TypeError("add() only accepts integer arguments")

        if isinstance(numbers, (list, set, tuple)):
            for num in numbers:
                if not isinstance(num, int):
                    raise TypeError("add() only accepts integer arguments")
            integer_total += sum(numbers)
        else:
            integer_total += numbers

    return integer_total
```

Optimally, I'd like to call this isinstance once. I tried using: isinstance(numbers, (list, set, tuple, string, float)) but I do not think I have implemented it right.

Comment: Do you want to allow lists, sets and tuples to be passed? Your code first throws an error if these types are present at all, but then continues (even though unreachable) to attempt to add all the elements of the object if they are all ints.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned trying to use (sic, syntax errors aside):

```
isinstance(numbers, (list, set, tuple, string, float))
```

to try to catch all your exceptions, but there are still lots of other types that could be passed which **won't** be caught at this step.

All you need to do is verify that the argument **is** an integer, which you already do (twice in fact)! Simply check that the argument is (or is not) an integer, then handle it appropriately, either by raising an error or adding to the sum.

```
def add(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        raise TypeError("add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'")

    integer_total = 0

    for numbers in args:
        if not isinstance(numbers, int):
            raise TypeError("add() only accepts integer arguments")
        else:
            integer_total = integer_total + numbers

    return integer_total
```

Comment: No worries. Please accept as answer if this helped.